# How to get a "notification" when a game update is pushed to steam?

Tags: node.js, steam, steam-web-api

So I want to use something like the [Steam Web API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview) to check whether a game has been updated on the Store, such as when Factorio beta is updated from 1.1.12 to 1.1.13. I want to use this for server management, as the server-side updates are managed by Factorio servers (not Steam), so the server-side updates are available immediately. Clientside updates are generally managed by Steam though, so I need to wait for updating a server when Steam releases the update.
Is it therefore possible to check whether Steam releases a new game update?

Comment: It's not notification friendly, but you could poll [Steam's Web API](https://steamapi.xpaw.me/#ISteamApps/UpToDateCheck) periodically, if you can get the installed app version(s) from your code.